# communicate with a driver from a kernel module

Tags: linux, driver, system-calls, kernel-module

I want to communicate with a driver (/dev device) from a kernel module. I have an application and some kernel modules associated with it. From the lowest KM I want to read and write to the driver. What should I do? I have read that writing and reading files from the KM is not a good choice. Is there any other way? Could I use the header files of the driver? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the driver exports functions (for example via `EXPORT_SYMBOL`) you can simply call those from your own module.